# How to download OpenJDK for Windows from Red Hat

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, download, redhat

I need a JDK for VSCode Java Extension Pack. It wants the Red Hat OpenJDK v11 or later. Despite having installed Oracle JDK v8, 11.0.5, 13.0.1, and 15.0.1 it still wants the one from Red Hat. I'm using Windows.

When going to the download location `https://developers.redhat.com/products/openjdk/download` I'm greeted with "Start today with Red Hat's implementation of OpenJDK—**a free and open source** implementation of the Java Platform, Standard Edition (Java SE)"; emphasis is mine.

Upon clicking on a link to download the "jdk-11.0.8-x64 MSI" installer for Windows I have to log in and then provide a whole lot of personal details including employer details, private address, and **accepting an Enterprise Agreement, which mentions some fees**.

Is it possible to download this "Free and open source" OpenJDK under reasonable terms? I won't be blindly accepting an agreement worded like that, because I don't want to sign any Enterprise Agreement with Red Hat as a casual independent developer. Even Oracle doesn't require me to log in to be able to download JDK. If only their SDK worked...

Please help. Thanks in advance.

[image: Red Hat page]

Comment: [It doesn't say that Red Hat's JDK is required](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial#_installing-a-java-development-kit-jdk)

Comment: I was able to use Oracle JDK - my JAVA_HOME pointed to JDK for version 8 for some reason, after switching it to JDK 15 it started working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The agreement is about if you purchase something from Red Hat that costs money then you agree to pay for it in a timely manner. You have to agree to it to get a Red Hat account. There is no fee to download OpenJDK after doing that.

If you prefer an implementation that doesn't require an account to download, try [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/).

Comment: That's unreasonable to be forced to give all personal and employer details, plus acceptance of the EA to download a free product. Why are they harvesting personal data so hard? I think my willingness to use any Red Hat product has ended. Many other vendors have an option "Skip to download" or something like that. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Probably because the only reason to download it from Red Hat is if you're an existing or prospective enterprise customer.